# How to compare JSONObject with a Query

Tags: android, json, android-studio

How to compare this:

```
search.setName(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
```

with:

```
text.toString()
```

Can you help me please?

This is my code

```
final Query query = new Query(text.toString())
                    .setHitsPerPage(50); 

            index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void requestCompleted( @Nullable JSONObject content, @Nullable AlgoliaException error) {

                   try {

                       list.clear(); 
                        JSONArray hits = content.getJSONArray("hits");

                        for (int i =0; i < hits.length(); i++) {

                            Model search = new Model(); 

                            search.setName(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome"));
                            search.setCity(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("city"));
                            search.setcountry(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("country"));
                           
                            list.add(search);
   

                        }
                       searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
```

Comment: What you have tried with? Seems like you are doing this in android and that text.toString() is actually a 'TextView' object. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it on android. Text.toString () is an "EditText".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right and you're comparing android `TextView` instance text, you need to call:

```
boolean match = text.getText().toString() == hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
```

text.toString() returns the instance hascode not the string inside `TextView`

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives an error "cannot resolve symbol "getText ". I want to compare if they are the same. "Text" is a "EditText"

Comment: `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`. Can you share the code where you have assigned the value to type `EditText` to text? I thing you are assigning it to something else, some superclass of `TextView` or the  `View` type.

Comment: Oh my bad, I just copied you code, I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Share the code how you defined `EditText`

Comment: I understood my mistake. I will reformulate my question. I want to know which of 
these codes contains the text inserted in "textoDigitado"?

"pesquisa.setNome(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome"));
pesquisa.setCidade(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("cidade")); 
pesquisa.setPais(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("pais")); 
pesquisa.setRegiao(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("regiao"));"

Comment: I guess you have again asked a wrong question. `textoDigitado` is of type `Editable` and you haven't used in any of the lines you added in you comment. Although I see from the code in the below answer that its used in building `Query` instance.

Comment: If you want to know which of the `EditText` have the `textoDigitado` text then that has to be the one you added the `TextWatcher` to i.e. `EditText pesquisa`

Comment: I've already managed to do what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
public class procurar extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText pesquisa;
private PesquisaInicialAdapter pesquisaInicialAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerListaPesquisa;
List<Model> listPesquisa = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_procurar);

    CollectionReference pais = db.collection("Locais");

    pesquisa = findViewById(R.id.idPesquisar);
    recyclerListaPesquisa = findViewById(R.id.idRecyclerViewListaPesquisa);


    Client client = new Client("user" "pass"); 
    final Index index = client.getIndex("Locais");


    recyclerListaPesquisa.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerListaPesquisa.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    pesquisaInicialAdapter = new PesquisaInicialAdapter(listPesquisa, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerListaPesquisa.setAdapter(pesquisaInicialAdapter);

        pais.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            listPesquisa.add(document.toObject(Model.class));
                        }

                        pesquisaInicialAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                    } else {
                        Log.d("", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });


    pesquisa.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable textoDigitado) {

            final Query query = new Query(textoDigitado.toString())
                    .setHitsPerPage(50); 

            index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void requestCompleted( @Nullable JSONObject content, @Nullable AlgoliaException error) {

                   try {

                       listPesquisa.clear();
                        JSONArray hits = content.getJSONArray("hits");

                        for (int i =0; i < hits.length(); i++) {

                            Model pesquisa = new Model();

           pesquisa.setNome(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome"));
           pesquisa.setCidade(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("cidade")); 
           pesquisa.setPais(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("pais")); 
           pesquisa.setRegiao(hits.getJSONObject(i).getString("regiao"));                                                                           

                            listPesquisa.add(pesquisa);

                        }

                       pesquisaInicialAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```